# Re-Use of Bundle's savedState created in OnCreate

Tags: android, bundle

In my Application, If any exception occurs in Activity then with the help of intent I'm redirecting that Activity with current `Activity and Exception` to `Error Page Activity` with some error message and there is a also a button named `Try Again` and on the click event of that button, I am opening that Activity Again where exception has occurred. Here my Question is, On click of that `Try Again` button how to open Activity with its previous `onCreate Bundle savedInstanceState`.

I tried to find it on google but not getting any desired answer.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the bundle to the error activity with intent, pass it back to the activity that generated error and read it inside the onCreate method.

Sending data with intent:

```
Intent lIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
        Bundle lBundle = new Bundle();
        //put data into bundke
        lIntent.putExtra("someBundleData", lBundle);
        startActivity(lIntent);
```

Receivng data (onCreate method):

```
Intent lStartingIntent = getIntent();
Bundle lSomeBundleData = lStartingIntent.getBundleExtra("someBundleData");
```

Comment: Oh then how should I override new bundle state with my previous bundle ?

Comment: I guess you should call `super.onCreate(oldBundle);` where **oldBundle** is a `Bundle` from your destroyed `Activity`. But I am not sure if this is legal in means of framework, as this `Bundle` contains information very relevant to your destroyed `Activity`, and is intended to be destroyed with it.

Comment: If I were you, I would grab only the **necessary extras** from old Activity Bundle, then put it to a new Bundle, and pass to the Intent, which re-starts your Activity, as you've described

Comment: Can I have any example related to this ?

Comment: Here you have snipplet